# Retrieve a hashed password

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access, hash, passwords

I already could make the password to become not stored as the original text in the database. But while I want to retrieve it and check between the entered password with in the database, the error appears

> Value cannot be null

on this line of code:

```
string verifyHashedPassword = Convert.ToString(Crypto.VerifyHashedPassword(_registration.hashedPassword, this.textBox2.Text));
```

Here is the code that I am using for Login:

```
  string connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data  Source=..\db1.accdb";

  Registration _registration = new Registration();

  private void CheckUserDatabase(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
        {
            string query = "SELECT [Username], [Password], [UserType], [UserStore] FROM [Member] WHERE [Username] = @Username AND [Password] = @Password";

            string verifyHashedPassword = Convert.ToString(Crypto.VerifyHashedPassword(_registration.hashedPassword, this.textBox2.Text));

            conn.Open();

            using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Username", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar);
                cmd.Parameters["@Username"].Value = this.textBox1.Text;

                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar);
                cmd.Parameters["@Password"].Value = verifyHashedPassword;

                using (OleDbDataReader dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (dReader.Read())
                    {
                        UserInformation.CurrentLoggedInUser = (string)dReader["Username"];
                        UserInformation.CurrentLoggedInUserType = (string)dReader["UserType"];
                        UserInformation.CurrentLoggedInUserStore = (string)dReader["UserStore"];
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        RecursiveClearTextBoxes(this.Controls);
                    }

                    dReader.Close();
                    conn.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the code for Registration:

```
    string connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=..\db1.accdb";

    private void AddDatabase(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
           string query = "INSERT INTO [Member] ([Username], [Password], [UserType],              [UserStore]) VALUES (@Username, @Password, @UserType, @UserStore)";

            string hashedPassword = Crypto.HashPassword(this.textBox2.Text);

            OleDbConnection _conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);

            _conn.Open();

            using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, _conn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Username", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar);
                cmd.Parameters["@Username"].Value = this.textBox1.Text;

                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar);
                cmd.Parameters["@Password"].Value = hashedPassword;

                cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserType", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar);
                cmd.Parameters["@UserType"].Value = this.textBox3.Text;

                cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserStore", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar);
                cmd.Parameters["@UserStore"].Value = this.textBox4.Text;

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                DialogResult _dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Added Successfully", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK);

                if (_dialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    this.Hide();

                    this.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Any help?

Your answer much appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: Find out what is null and change it? This is a case for a Debugger, not for SO.

Comment: as nvoigt said .. set a breakpoint on the line where it fails and look into the variables to see which one is null. If you know which it is, then further inspect why it is.

Comment: Why did you post the same question twice?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22341249/value-cannot-be-null-while-crypto-ing-the-password